Unable to save values in sequence during parallel processing in Python
I have below code:
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta
from time import sleep
from services.ldap import LDAP
import aiohttp
import os

from conf.settings import Settings as settings
import multiprocessing
from queue import Queue
from services import mongo
import asyncio


def run_parallel( user , users_list): # to_add is passed as an argument
    overall_list = []
    ldap_server = os.environ.get("LDAPSERVER")
    ldap_username = os.environ.get("SERVICE_ACCOUNT_USERNAME")
    ldap_password = os.environ.get("SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD")
    ldap_base_dn = os.environ.get("BASE_DN")
    ldap_users = LDAP(ldap_server ,ldap_username ,ldap_password ,ldap_base_dn)
    settings.log.info("Search Begins for User---->",user)
    #users_list.append(user)
    users_list.append("L1->L6")
    users_metadata = ldap_users.search(user)
    while users_metadata['ntid'] != users_metadata["ldap_manager"]: 
        users_metadata = ldap_users.search(user)
        settings.log.info(users_metadata["ldap_manager"])
        #manager is now an employee
        user = users_metadata['ldap_manager']
        users_list.append(users_metadata['ldap_manager'])
          
    overall_list = overall_list + users_list
    #users_list.append(user)
    settings.log.info("Overall List",overall_list)
    


class LDAPUserSearch:
    def __init__(self, users_ntid_list):
        self.users_ntid_list = users_ntid_list 
        self.run()

    def run(self):
        users_ntid_list = ["rohan", "patel", "nancy", "umar", "john"]
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=5)
        results = [pool.apply_async(run_parallel, (user, self.users_ntid_list)) # num_to_add is passed as an argument
                      for user in self.users_ntid_list]
        roots = [r.get() for r in results]
        pool.close()
        pool.terminate()
        pool.join()

i want to save the list of user and its search results.
i.e "Search Begins for User---->",user
and then in the while loop whatever results i get i want to save it in the list.
Due to parallel processing i am not getting all the data for 5 users.
I should get the expected output as:
rohan manager is searched in the while loop.
["rohan","rohan manager","rohan's manager manager", "patel" ,"patel manager","patel manager's manager" ... and so on]

Multiprocessing create new interpreter processes, serialize the input data and send it to workers. The output data are serialized back and accessed by the master interpreter process. You cannot mutate data of the master process in workers (unless you explicitly share data with something like monitors AFAIK which is generally limited and often not a good idea either). Since you do not return anything in your function, there is no output nor anything that is mutated in the parent master interpreter.

In your case, I expect threads to be better suited since LDAP operations should be latency bound. In fact, theoretically, all of this should be better with an asynchronous serial code (unless profiling show that you are CPU bound).
